# Minecraft PE duplicate pack detected

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was looking at this add-on for Minecraft PE but when I tried to download it, it said,

`Cannot download this add on, duplicate pack detected.`

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, as you have found out, you have a duplicate pack. You should check the files with a file manager and look at the files in internal storage: `/games/com.mojang/behavior_packs`  See there if there is a behavior pack with the same name as the one you are trying to install.

Comment: Did you a word in the second sentence?

Comment: What one? What do you mean?

Comment: Your second sentence is "You a duplicate pack" which seems to be missing a word. :)

Comment: I fixed it. It was supposed to be "You have a duplicate pack"